# Syntax error on creating and extracting name variable using MsgBox

Tags: vba, syntax-error

I am trying to execute a macro to create and extract name variable using MsgBox. I have tried to run it without '_' in the MsgBox code, it didn't work. It shows a message that there is a syntax error in the code defining name equal to Steve Jobs.

```
Sub test1()
Dim name as string, lname as string, fname as string
name = “Steve Jobs”
lname = right(name, 4)
fname = left(name,5)
Msgbox “First name is” & fname & “” & “ the number of characters are” & len(fname)
Msgbox “Surname is” & fname & “” & “ the number of characters are” _ & len(fname)
End Sub
```

Comment: Could it be because your quotes look funny? e.g. `"` versus `” “`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test1()
Dim name As String, lname As String, fname As String
name = "Steve Jobs"
lname = Right(name, 4)
fname = Left(name, 5)
MsgBox "First name is " & fname & "" & " the number of characters is " & _
Len(fname)
MsgBox "Surname is " & lname & "" & " the number of characters is " & _
Len(lname)
End Sub
```

The quote mark you use looks weird, this way it should be fine

Comment: One more thing that I assume you know is that this code isn't going to work properly for almost any other name because of the way you defined lname and fname.

Comment: This works. Why is an underscore put after ampersand in the MsgBox line? Thanks.

Comment: @KBh it is a space followed by an underscore and a linebreak. This means the code in the next line is handled as it was in the same line. It's kind a soft line break just to improve code visibility and avoid very long code lines. It is the same as writing all in one line.

Comment: @KBh, if this answer provided you a solution to your question, then you should mark it as accepted

Comment: @Kbh That matter is described well by ashleedawg in the answer below. If you are satisfied with my answer you may select it as an accepted answer, that's how you say thanks on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The `_` you're referring to is a line continuation character.

Also, the quotation marks in your post are incorrect - although it may be a result of how you copied the text to this site (perhaps you had to "email it to yourself" in the process). Once the quotation marks are changed from `“` and `”` to `"`. then either of these will run fine:

***with* line continuation:**

```
Msgbox “Surname is” & fname & “” & “ the number of characters are” & _
    len(fname)
```

***without* line continuation:**

```
Msgbox “Surname is” & fname & “” & “ the number of characters are” & len(fname)
```

**I think this is what you're *trying* to do:**

```
Debug.Print "Surname is """ & lName & """ and the number of characters is " & Len(lName)
```

In your example, you're using `fName` for both first name & last name. Also, this is how we can put quotes around a variable.